# Change body bgcolor on hovering a div, using CSS only

Tags: css

I want that when I hover an element(a box made with css), the `background color` of the body changes from one color to another, for example white to red. The problem is that this should be done using css only and no javascript. And if javascript has to be neccesarily be used, then the color should change back to the previous one on mouse out.

---------------EDIT---------------

Actually I was trying this:

```
body{backgroung: #000;}
#div{some properties}
body #div:hover{background: #fff;}
```

Comment: Just show us what have you tried so far.. even it is wrong. I hope you tried something before asking.

Comment: This can be done using only [**CSS**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1014861/1577396) but it is not [**recommended**](http://css-tricks.com/parent-selectors-in-css/).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Pure CSS experiment:

http://jsfiddle.net/Tymek/yrKRX/

**HTML**

```
<div id="trigger"></div>
<div id="bg"></div>​
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    height: 100%;
}

#bg {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    widht: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    background: #EEE;
}

#trigger {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 136px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -68px 0 0 -100px;
    background: #333;
    z-index: 2;
}

/* KEY */
#trigger:hover ~ #bg {
    background: #EE0;
}​
```

Comment: Thank you, for your reply. This css script works!!! Actually i needed one without any javascript and you didi it.

Answer (score 1):

Please use like this

```
<html>
   <body>

     <style type="text/css">   

       .top{  
           background:red;
       }

       .top2{   
           background:white;
       }
     </style>

    <div class="top" onmouseover="this.className='top2'" 
                    onmouseout="this.className='top'">Here</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The background color of the body should change and not that div on which one must hover to change it.

Comment: You can use elements in which you want instead of div.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `:hover` selector. 
It seems pretty straight forward unless you are doing something very different.

Check following example for reference:

```
.classname {
    background-color:white;
 } 

 .classname:hover {
    background-color:red;
 }
```

Comment: The background color of the body should change and not that div on which one must hover to change it.

Comment: After seeing your edited question @Tymek 's answer is the best solution. Please mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score -2):

**[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zN983/1/)**

You have many typo's in your code such as mispelling `background` as `backgroung` and treating `div` as an ID (`#div`).

**CSS** (*with explanation to typos*)

```
body{background: #000;}                /*backgroung (mis-spelled)*/
div{width:100px;                       /*#div (treated as ID)*/
    height:100px;
    border:1px solid black;}
```

To hover over a parent tag you must **compulsorily** use javascript or jQuery. you may be getting doubt that why there is no css property to select the parent tag, if so, then you can go through this **[interesting link](http://css-tricks.com/parent-selectors-in-css/)** . To avoid parent selector concept in most of cases we can evade using positioning in CSS (check Tymek's solution).

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div").hover(function(){
        $(this).parent(this).css('background-color','red');
    });

    $("div").mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).parent(this).css('background-color','white');
    });
});​
```

Assuming you are new to jQuery, give a link in `head` tag of HTML, something like below to make the above function work.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Check this **[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zN983/1/)**

Comment: @Zachdev I know how to do using [**CSS**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1014861/1577396) but it is not [**recommended**](http://css-tricks.com/parent-selectors-in-css/). BTW, dont just read the title, read the post too.