# CSS Change the background while hovering

Tags: css, background, hover

SOLVED THANKS TO ELIEL's [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14039723/change-body-bgcolor-on-hovering-a-div-using-css-only/14039989#14039989)

What I want to do is to change the **body** background while hovering on a div, but I can't acquire that, what I get is the **div** background changed.

I do have the color on the **body**, which is black, and I want to change it to white if I hover on the div1.

That is what I have tried

```
body{
    background-color:black;
}
#div1:hover {
    background-color:white;
}
```

But this changes my div1 background color instead of the body background color.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14039989/1014858) seems to be a solution to your problem.

Comment: Alternatively, you will need to use JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

To cleanly edit the hover state of an element, you need to target both the neutral and hover states, like this:

```
div {
    background-color:red;
} 
div:hover {
    background-color:blue;
}
```

The problem with your code above is that you are targeting the body, then targeting the `:hover` state of a different element. If you want to change the `body` hover state, you would use:

```
body{
    background-color:black;
}
body:hover {
    background-color:white;
}
```

Bear in mind that while the entire browser window will show `body` styles, only the sections containing content will respond to `body:hover`

Comment: What I want to do, or try to do is to change the body background while hovering the div.

Comment: The easiest way to do that would be to place a wrapper `div` immediately inside the `body` with , then apply the styles and `:hover` state to that. Changing one element while targeting another with CSS can be a bit messy

Answer (score 0):

You can try with Javascript.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function changeBgColor(color) {
    document.body.style.background = color;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id='div1' onmouseover="changeBgColor('green');" onmouseout="changeBgColor('yellow');">test</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am trying to just use css and html (just focusing on learn those two).