# How can I change entire Website Background Color when I Mouseover

Tags: html, css, hover, background-color, mouseover

How can I change ENTIRE WEBSITE Background Color when I Mouseover image,text etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change body bgcolor on hovering a div, using CSS only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14039723/change-body-bgcolor-on-hovering-a-div-using-css-only)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hope this will help to you.but you may need little bit jquery.paste this and try it.you may need internet connection because I have linked jquery online.

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>jquery</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
 .classOne{
  background-color: orange;
  color: white;
 }
  
 .changeme{
   cursor:pointer;
   }

</style>

</head>

<body>
 <p class="changeme">change the body background color</p>
 

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $(".changeme").mouseenter(function(){
   $('body').addClass("classOne");
  });
  $(".changeme").mouseleave(function(){
   $('body').removeClass("classOne");
  });
  

 });
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

you can use this with any other element such any img,div, etc....

or, if you want to change only the body background with css,you can use hover like this

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>jquery</title>

<style type="text/css">
  
  body:hover{
   background-color: orange;
   color: white;
  }

</style>

</head>

<body>
 <p>change the body background color</p>
 

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your code and making a guess, I imagine you could use a css selector more specifically `:hover` if you just want it to change when you hover and at no other point. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp